# are Hierarchical SIngletons in Java possible?

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I've been toying with an interesting idea (No idea if I'll include it in any code, but it's fun to think about)

Let's say we have a program that requires a large number of classes, all of a certain subclass. And those classes all need to be singletons. Now, we could write the singleton pattern for each of those classes, but it seems wasteful to write the same code over and over, and we already have a common base class. It would be really nice to create a getSingleton method of A that when called from a subclass, returns a singleton of the B class (cast to class A for simplicity)

```
class A{
     public A getSingleton(){
         //Wizardry
     }
}
class B extends A{
}

A blargh = B.getSingleton()
A gish = B.getSingleton()
if(A == B)
    System.out.println("It works!")
```

It seems to me that the way to do this would be to recognize and call B's default constructor (assuming we don't need to pass anything in.) I know a little of the black magic of reflection in Java, but i'm not sure if this can be done.

Anyone interested in puzzling over this?

Comment: you rarely need a real singleton.  In quite some apps you may need objects which you'll want to have exactly one instance during the lifecycle of your application.  But you probably *should not* use a singleton for that, because it shall complicate (or prevent) proper unit testing.  What you want is something that is nearly a singleton, but not exactly.  Framework like Spring can help in such cases.

Comment: @Chris S. - how is your comment so different from my answer?   We're both suggesting that singletons aren't the answer.  So why are you saying I'm "not helping"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, I see no reason why something similar to this can't be done. Your exact scheme won't work because your `getSingleton` is `static` (even though you fail to declare it as such) so it can't tell which class it's being called for. Change it to `static A getSingleton(Class cls)`, and it might be workable.

However, is this really that much of a win over having a one-liner `getSingleton` in each derived class?

For starters, your one `getSingleton` returns `A`, so if someone calls it for `B`, they get back an `A` and have to downcast to use it as a `B`.

Also, the scheme isn't exactly transparent.

Sure, it's fun to think about, but I'd look for more compelling reasons before doing this in any production system.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it that way indicating the class: (in fact you can use for all classes if they have public noargs constructor)

```
//Code not tested
class A {
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Class,Object> instances=new ConcurrentHashMap();

    private A(){}

    public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T extends A> classe) {
       Object instance=instances.get(classe);
       if(instance==null) {
         instance=createInstance(classe,instance);
       }
       return instance;
    }

    protected <T> T createInstance(Class<T> classe) {
      return classe.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Beware, you'll need some fiddling: the syntax is wrong at times, and there is a crucial `instances.put(classe, instance)` missing after the call to `createInstance(classe)` [**not** `createInstance(classe, instance)` as above].

Note that you can also use this in case your constructor needs parameters. Just declare the necessary constructor in class A, and use `classe.getConstructor(ParameterClass.class).newInstance(parameter);` to get your instances.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea.  Another way of reducing duplicate code is to use a tool to handle the creation of your "Singleton"s.  A common way of doing this in Java is to use a dependency injection tool such as [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html), which allows you to define all the types that you want to be singletons, and then request those types from Spring when you need them.  Spring then ensures that it only ever creates one of each type that is requested.  There is almost no code duplication.

This has the upside of not forcing Singleton behavior on the type itself.  Many of the problems with Singletons revolve around how impossibly hard they make it to test code effectively because of their global state (I've been on projects where I've spent substantial time helping people figure out how to fix tests that have been broken because two different tests are modifying a singleton).  Using Spring you can get singleton like behavior, but also choose to create separate instances of the types when it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no", it's not possible.

If inheritance means "IS-A", then B is an A, and they aren't singletons anymore.

"...large number of classes, all of a certain subclass. And those classes all need to be singletons..."

I just re-read this.  Aren't "large number" and "singleton" contradictory?

Personally, I wouldn't want to have to maintain something like this.  I think it's an example of an overuse of the the singleton pattern, which was close to being [voted off the island at OOPSLA](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=29794), and excessive cleverness.

Google has written [utilities](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/) to identify singletons in their code so they can be removed.  Still want to litter you code with them?

Comment: Depends on how we define helping the questioner.  If you post code to help someone do something that is not recommended, are you really helping?  I'd rather tell and be told.